# To find a particular word written in a string type field in AX 2012?

Tags: dynamics-ax-2009, x++, dynamics-ax-2012, ax

Is it possible in AX 2012 to find a particular word/words written in a string type field in AX 2012 table or form.
e.g, I have a field named **Memo** in my table named test. In that field I have a written a text as:
*Hello,
 We need to confirm you that your < mobileNumber > is successfully attached with your account no. < Account >.*

Now, I need to find all texts written inside tags "<" and ">".
Furthermore I require to replace these texts according to my need.
Please tell if its possible in AX 2012 or if there is any other option that I can opt to fulfill my need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find every occurence of "<" and ">" using the strScan function 
[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/aa866529(v=ax.50).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/aa866529%28v=ax.50%29.aspx)

Use that to find the location of the "<"s and matching ">"

Use SubStr [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/aa677836(v=ax.50).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/aa677836%28v=ax.50%29.aspx) to find what is between "<" and ">", and apply your replacement based on that  (using strPoke [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/aa850123(v=ax.50).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/aa850123%28v=ax.50%29.aspx))

A useful AX2009 string class that utiliseses these methods and that may be of some help can be found here
http://axgeek.blogspot.co.uk/2010/04/string-function-class.html , it should not take much effort to convert to 2012.

Of particular interest to you is the replace method.

However it may be simpler to have the memo as "Hello, We need to confirm you that your %1 is successfully attached with your account no. %2.", and to insert the values using strFmt
http://www.axaptapedia.com/index.php?title=StrFmt

Of course the .Net String.Replace method is also available.
see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc584291.aspx and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.replace.aspx